# how to sum string values which are coming in array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [Asan_Name_Val] => 447
            [Actual_Ratio] => 15/00/15,04/05/05
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Asan_Name_Val] => 447
            [Actual_Ratio] => 10/05/11,00/06/05
        )
)
```

The actual ratio value should sum with it values like 15+10=15,00+05=05,15+11=26 .....
So The desired output I want In this format

```
Array
(
    [Asan_Name_Val] => 447
    [Actual_Ratio] => 25/05/26,04/11/10
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried but it did not work ,

Comment: Share your code in the description of the question.

Comment: The down votes are most likely because you haven't included any code attempt. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: is `15/00/15,04/05/05` a string? Never seen such numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a hacky solution in PHP.
Will work but strongly advice you to optimize.

```
<?php
$myArray = array(
  0 => array(
  'Asan_Name_Val' => '447',
  'Actual_Ratio' => '15/00/15,04/05/05'
  ),
  1 => array(
  'Asan_Name_Val' => '447',
  'Actual_Ratio' => '10/05/11,00/06/05'
  )
);
$sums = array_fill(0,6,'0');
foreach($myArray as $arr){
  $ratio = $arr['Actual_Ratio'];
  $j=0;
  for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    $sums[$i] = sprintf("%02d", $sums[$i]+substr($ratio,$j,2));
    $j = $j+3;
  }
}
$finalRatio = "$sums[0]/$sums[1]/$sums[2],$sums[3]/$sums[4]/$sums[5]";

$desiredArray['Asan_Name_Val'] = '447';
$desiredArray['Actual_Ratio'] = $finalRatio;

print_r($desiredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a flexible and clean approach:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'Asan_Name_Val' => "447",
        'Actual_Ratio' => "15/00/15,04/05/05"
    ],
    [
        'Asan_Name_Val' => "447",
        'Actual_Ratio' => "10/05/11,00/06/05"
    ]
];
$output = [];
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output, $formatter) {
    $values = explode("/", $entry['Actual_Ratio']);
    foreach($values as &$value) {
        $value = $formatter->parse($value);
    }
    $output[$entry['Asan_Name_Val']][] = $values;
});

array_walk($output, function(&$entry, $key) use ($formatter) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($entry[0]); $i++) {
        $sums[] = $formatter->format(array_sum(array_column($entry, $i)));    
    }
    $entry = [
        'Asan_Name_Val' => $key,
        'Actual_Ratio' => implode("/", $sums)
    ];
});

print_r(array_values($output));
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Asan_Name_Val] => 447
            [Actual_Ratio] => 25/5/26,04/11/10
        )

)
```